# Building a table with a sequence of sequences

Tags: clojure

What I have:

- Collection (map in this instance, Seqable more generally) of items I want to display in a Markdown table ([whichever flavour of Markdown reddit uses](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/73581)).
- Sequence of accessor functions that produce the contents of each column of the desired table when mapped over the collection.
- Sequence of those column mappings: `(for [x accessors] (map x coll))`

What I'm trying to do:

- Append `(repeat "\n")` to the sequence of mappings, as the item separator.
- `apply interleave` over the sequence-of-sequences.
- Consume the resulting sequence with `clojure.string/join` to insert the 'table cell separator' "|" and glue it all together.

I just can't seem to get the first step working. All my attempts seem to append the infinite sequence of \n itself rather than that sequence as a single object in a seq of seqs or similar issues.  A little help?

Edit: A little input/output example does make sense for something like this so I'd better add it. For simplicity we'll just list numbers and functions of them. Input:

```
(markdown-table [[[identity] "Number"]
                 [[(partial * 2)] "Doubled"]] (range 6))
```

(The strings and such are for making column names - might change that setup later but you can see the accessor functions in there. Just listing the number itself and its doubling.)
For this I have the sequence `((0 1 2 3 4 5) (0 2 4 6 8 10))` and want to end up with the sequence

```
(0 0 "\n" 1 2 "\n" 2 4 "\n" 3 6 "\n" 4 8 "\n" 5 10 "\n")
```

Comment: show input and desired output at least, code if you have it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for [interpose](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/interpose)

```
(def items [1 2 3 4 5])

(def accesors [(fn [x] (inc x))
               (fn [x] (- 10 x))])

(def mappings (for [x accesors]
                (map x items)))
=> ((2 3 4 5 6) (9 8 7 6 5))


(interpose "\n" mappings)
=> ((2 3 4 5 6) "\n" (9 8 7 6 5))
```

**Edit** after your sample:

```
 (map (fn [& args] 
         (apply (juxt identity (partial * 2)) args)) 
      (range 6))
 => ([0 0] [1 2] [2 4] [3 6] [4 8] [5 10])
```

Then just use interpose on it.

```
(def accessors [(fn [x] (identity x))
                (fn [x] (* x 2))])

(def mappings (map (fn [& args] 
                     (apply (apply juxt accessors) args)) 
                   (range 6)))

(interpose "\n" mappings)
=> ([0 0] "\n" [1 2] "\n" [2 4] "\n" [3 6] "\n" [4 8] "\n" [5 10])
```

Comment: Useful but not quite the interleaving I'm trying to achieve - I'd want the first element of each mapping in order, then a \n, then the second element and so on. Probably my fault for not giving an example like edbond said.

Comment: Ooh, that's neat. Never really had cause to use `juxt` before, but that's a neat application of it. Would still need to `flatten` after but it gets the right ordering.

Answer (score 2):

Clojure already has something similar to what you are trying to do

```
(defn markdown-table 
  [specs xs] 
  (clojure.pprint/print-table 
    (for [x xs] 
      (into {} 
        (for [{:keys [label fn]} specs] [label (fn x)])))))

(markdown-table [{:label "Number", :fn identity} 
                 {:label "Doubled", :fn (partial * 2)}] 
                (range 6))
```

Output (could wrap in `with-out-str`):

```
| Number | Doubled |
|--------+---------|
|      0 |       0 |
|      1 |       2 |
|      2 |       4 |
|      3 |       6 |
|      4 |       8 |
|      5 |      10 |
```

Comment: Did not know about that one. Gets pretty close, although the top part that shows columns doesn't work out with Markdown and I'd have to go back to it for fix-up. Still, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @user1571406 You bet. As with the rest of Clojure, clojure.pprint is open source, so you could also modify a copy as desired for your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

While responding I appear to have found a way that works using my original approach. By placing the mapping-sequences in a vector, I can append the \n sequence as one value to interleave rather than as infinitely many values as with `concat`, `cons` and so on. The resulting code was

```
(defn- markdown-table
  "Create Markdown for a table displaying a collection
  Columns defines the columns to show - give pairs of accessor sequence and display names."
  [columns coll]
  (let[columns-def (str "|" (clojure.string/join "|" (concat (map second columns)
                                                            "\n"
                                                            ;;All columns are center aligned, for now.
                                                            (map (constantly ":--:") columns)))
                       "\n")
       accessors (for [[x _] columns] (apply comp (reverse x))) ;;Reverse so composition is leftmost-first
       columns (for [x accessors] (map x coll))
       item-separated (conj (vec columns) (repeat "\n"))
       cells (apply interleave item-separated)
       ](clojure.string/join "|" (cons columns-def cells))))
```

Still not quite sure about the way it handles column definitions but it seems to give the right output.